# Leaflet GeoJSON with projected coordinates (3857)

Tags: leaflet, geojson, web-mercator

I am trying to get a GeoJSON with projected coordinates to show in Leaflet.

I have no problems loading GeoJSON with lat/lng (EPSG:4326). Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/f4r4tqc3/) where I load the GeoJSON with unprojected lat/lng.

I am using the Leaflet 1.0.0-beta.2 (954e83d) in the fiddle but I am happy to use another version.

I am aware of the coordsToLatLng method of L.geoJson but no idea how to make this work.

This is the GeoJSON with the projected (EPSG:3857) coordinates.

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
            "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857"
        }
    },
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {

        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [[
            [-625570.6, 6465993.0],
            [-305006.9, 6696510.8],
            [-546330.2, 6768547.6],
            [-445478.6, 7053093.0],
            [-279794.0, 7056694.8],
            [-359034.5, 7337638.4],
            [-211359.0, 7485313.8],
            [62380.8,   6955843.3],
            [220861.7,  6909019.4],
            [91195.5,   6700112.6],
            [213658.1,  6682103.4],
            [-625570.6, 6465993.0]]]
        }
    }]
}
```

[image]

Notes: I am new to Leaflet. I come from a GIS background. I have a very good understanding of projections and transformations. I have a very good understanding of OpenLayers3. I use OL3 to do things such as this on a daily basis. The data in this post is obviously just an example. I am trying to learn Leaflet in order to compare the performance with OL3. I know how to use QGIS and can unproject the data manually but this is not the point of this post.

This is not a repost. I have checked every bit of information on coordsToLatLng but didn't find any good documentation and nothing like a working example. Certainly no fiddle.

Just saying this as I have read a lot of Leaflet posts on gis.stackexchange with half-a-code. And a lot of answers which suggest to change the data. I know that Leaflet is not a GIS system and the makers are not from a GIS background. In the last hour I have just read a lot of rubbish about Leaflet using EPSG:3857 as default SRS and WGS84 being an SRS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One option is to use [Proj4Leaflet](http://kartena.github.io/Proj4Leaflet/) to read the projected GeoJSON. If you have a variable called `sampleProjected` referencing your GeoJSON (and assuming you are using a projection that is defined in Proj4, as EPSG:3857 is), you could just add it like so:

```
L.Proj.geoJson(sampleProjected).addTo(map);
```

Here is an example comparing your projected data (in blue) with the unprojected data (dashed, in white):

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/ru7oyquq/

There is a small amount of offset, but on inspection, it is unclear whether this is due to the rounding of your unprojected sample or a problem with the proj4 implementation. The magnitudes and directions of the offsets are not uniform, so it may just be rounding. Projections can also be added or modified using the [`proj4.defs` method](https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js#named-projections).

Comment: Smashing. Thanks a lot. I was only exploring methods in the Leaflet library itself. The Proj4Leaflet seems to do everything I need.

Comment: I guess that's you? http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/o563bg44       - Brilliant!